# Excel: how to lowercase without losing newlines?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In Excel, if I have two lines in A1:

```
Hello
World
```

but if I go over to A2 and type `=lower(A1)`, I get:

```
helloworld
```

How can I preserve the newline between *Hello* and *World*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `=lower(A1)` and then turn on `Wrap Text` for that cell.

Answer (score 2):

Oddly enough, the newline is still there in A2, but the formatting of the cell is not showing it.  If you click on A1, click `Format Painter` and the click on A2 then the newline will appear.  You can also right click and select Format > Text

I don't think you can apply the right format as part of the formula though